# White, full size, non-gaming, illuminated keyboard with numpad, for PC with Windows

Tags: keyboards

I have the Logitech Illuminated keyboard, and I am very pleased with it. But one of the keys have fallen off, and I want to replace it with something similar, but white.

I would like it to be in a stylish design, as my PC is in our livingroom, but ultimately it has to be comfortable to write with, as I will use it a lot.

It would be nice if it was available with Norwegian key layout (ÆØÅ).

Apple keyboards are white, but I don't want that.

The A-Jazz AK30 is white and illuminated, but it's ugly as heck...

The closest one I have foud is the Trust KB-1500, but it seems to have gone out of production. At least, no online stores in Norway has it.

Price limit is around 100 EUR / 115 USD / 90 GBP / 1000 NOK.

Are there any other options?

Comment: It would help us narrow down options if you specified an upper price limit, or specify that you have no price limit.

Comment: @BennettYeo Price limit added.

Comment: With that price limit you can get a nice mechanical keyboard, but I'd not entirely sure about Norwegian keys.